# Ordering a query by cost

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been looking around for this but I can't seem to get it to work even though they've stated how to do it on certain blogs.

Here's my controller code:

```
@items = Item.order('cost ASC').all
```

Now, I was hoping this would sort the following code by the cost attribute, but it does not:

```
<ul id="items">
<% @items.each do |item| %> 
    <% if item.category == "consumables" %>
        <li>
            <div class="icon <%= item.friendly_id %>"></div> 
            <div class="tooltip">
                <h3><%= item.name %></h3>

                <div class="cost">
                    <span>Cost:</span> <%= item.cost %>
                </div>

                <p class="description">
                    <%= item.description %>
                </p>

                <% unless item.bonus.blank? %>
                    <p class="bonus">
                        <%= item.bonus %>               
                    </p>
                <% end %>

                <% unless item.active.blank? %>
                    <div class="active">
                        <h3>Active Ability</h3>
                        <p><%= item.active %></p>
                    </div>
                <% end %>               
            </div>
        </li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Ps. I don't know if my method of finding a category by a specific value is the most efficient way or according to the standards. If you know of a better and more efficient way to achieve this, please tell me how. :)

Answer (score 2):

maybe you have wrong database column type for `cost` column?

Also, you can safely omit `all`, and just use `@items = Item.order('cost ASC')`

Filtering by category, with order:

```
@items = Item.where(:category => 'consumables').order(:cost)   # ASC is by default
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Neither of those 2 options work though :/
It is still listing the items all messed up instead of in order of price.